# Not able to access nodes through webadmin interface.Same Graph is displaying in Neoclipse.Created nodes and relationships using java

Tags: neo4j

Below is the path setting code in java:
final String dbpath = "D:/neo4j-community-1.9.3-windows/neo4j-community-1.9.3/data/graph.db/";
GraphDatabaseService db =  new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(dbpath);

My neo4j-server.properties file::
org.neo4j.server.database.location=D:/neo4j-community-1.9.3-windows/neo4j-community-1.9.3/data/graph.db/
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=D:/neo4j-community-1.9.3-windows/neo4j-community-1.9.3/data/graph.db/

Not able to view the nodes in webadmin. when i try to display the same thing in neoclipse, it's perfectly working.  Pl help how to access nodes in webadmin portal.

Thanks,
Lokesh

Comment: In the shell, what does start n=node(*) return count(n) give you?

Comment: start n=node(*) return count(n) is not return any value for me.

Comment: Any value? Can you please paste exactly what you get on the shell prompt after executing this?

Comment: D:\neo4j-community-1.9.3-windows\neo4j-community-1.9.3\bin>Neo4jShell.bat
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (0)$ start n=node(*) return count(n)
>

Comment: it's not giving any value           
D:\neo4j-community-1.9.3-windows\neo4j-community-1.9.3\bin>Neo4jShell.bat
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (0)$ start n=node(*) return count(n)
>

Comment: No, execute it through your WebAdmin->Power Tool Console

Comment: In WebAdmin ,Power Tool Console is not opening..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please explain "not opening"? Is it there, can you click on it? what happens?
Also in the shell, it has to return something or does it hang?
Please try again:
start n=node(*) return count(n);

Comment: In WebAdmin ,Power Tool Console is visible, After clicking on the console, nothing is happening.not opening any page....

Comment: Whats your version of Neo4j? Also please check the Server Info tab- what is the value of store_dir? Did you try re-executing the query on the shell?